# IIS 10 The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, windows-server-2016, iis-10

Getting this error randomly on server here is the iis details.

> IIS version= 10.0.14393.0
>
> Windows server 2016

System.Web.Management.WebRequestErrorEvent, System.InvalidOperationException, An unhandled exception has occurred.The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.

```
Stack trace: at System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager()
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.EnsureResourceManager()
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName)
at ASP.usercontrols_uc_adduser_ascx.__BuildControlImage1()
at ASP.usercontrols_uc_adduser_ascx.__BuildControlcontractorUC_RadAjaxLoadingPanel1()
at ASP.usercontrols_uc_adduser_ascx.__BuildControlTree(secure_usercontrols_uc_adduser_ascx __ctrl)
at ASP.testpage_aspx.__BuildControlAddQuickContractor1()
at ASP.testpage_aspx.__BuildControlfrmMain()
at ASP.testpage_aspx.__BuildControlTree(secure_bidmain_aspx __ctrl)
at ASP.testpage_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**This error is coming randomly, but after recycling the app pool fixes it.** Can some help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if the case relates to the `Network/Route` issue. For example, some requests are discarded by the application gateway, which may be caused by the wrong NAT tables configured in the public firewall or router.  You could verify this by accessing the website with a local IP.
please check the below issue.
https://serverfault.com/questions/845606/iis-randomly-returning-inet-e-resource-not-found